# What are query_parameters and how do I pass them to Tweetstream::Client...filter(query_parameters = {})

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, parameter-passing

I am using the Tweetstream gem to retrieve statuses from Twitter.  This works:

```
 Tweetstream::Client.new('user', 'pw').track('alice', 'wonderland')
```

However, I know want to limit collecting tweets to both (i) specific users with (ii) specific words.  The Tweetstream gem provides this method:

```
 Tweetstream::Client.new('user', 'pw').filter(query_params = {}, &block)
```

But I can't figure out how to pass query_parameters = {}.  I'm trying it like this:

```
 Tweetstream::Client.new('user', 'pw').filter(
               {:follow => ('212380730', '23234252'), 
                :track => ('alice', 'wonderland') 
               } )
```

But I get errors related to syntax, e.g.,

> syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '}'

Thank you for your help!

The following is from the Tweetstream RDOC:
filter(query_params = {}, &block)

> Make a call to the statuses/filter method of the Streaming API, you may provide :follow, 
>   :track or both as options to follow the tweets of specified users or track keywords. This 
>   method is provided separately for cases when it would conserve the number of HTTP 
>   connections to combine track and follow.

This is the source of the .filter method:

```
 def filter(query_params = {}, &block)
   [:follow, :track].each do |param|
   if query_params[param].is_a?(Array)
   query_params[param] = query_params[param].collect{|q| q.to_s}.join(',')
     elsif query_params[param]
       query_params[param] = query_params[param].to_s
     end
   end
   start('statuses/filter', query_params.merge(:method => :post), &block)
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you mean [] instead of using () as your filter and track, the :filter and :track in query params are supposed to be arrays

Comment: Yes!  Thanks, corroded.  After many attempts, I finally figured it out somewhere in the wee hours of the night.  But +1 for the answer and confirmation.